# Assistance with nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am very new to Python, and need some help accessing a nested dictionary. Essentially, there is a lot of data under the *'data'* key, and I am having trouble accessing it as it is a `str` and not an `int`:

My dictionary looks like this:

```
{'data': [{'firstName': 'aaa', 'lastName': 'bbb', 'email': 'ccc', ...
```

I want to extract the *'firstName'*, *'lastName'*, and *'email'* for each user. This is my code so far:

```
if response.status_code == 200:
    data = json.loads(response.text)

    firstName = data['data']['firstName']
    lastName = data['data']['lastName']
    email = data['data']['email']

else:
    print(f"Error: {response.status_code}")
```

I am getting this error:

```
firstName = data['data']['firstName']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I can now print the first name using this code:

```
print(data['data'][0]['firstName'])
```

How would I loop this to print the firstname, lastname and email for each user?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The value of `data['data']` is a *list*, not a dict - notice the square brackets in your JSON!  You would need to index into that list to get the contained dictionaries - `data['data'][0]['firstName']` for example.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper - how would I loop this to give me the firstname, lastname and email for each user?